# No UI has been shown , when I deploy angular code through devops in Linux web app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-webapps

Please specify some solution for this. I have tried multiple ways through classic and as well as YAML for deployment in Linux web app . But the procees is correct and the pipelines shows succedeed, but there is not UI shown in linux web app , when i browse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: This doesn't offer enough information for the community to answer your question. At absolute minimum, we need to see your YAML. It'd also be useful to know if you're able to see static files (e.g., images) deployed, whether you're getting any markup returned, if there are e.g. console errors, &c.